# Automatic deploy of some bundles in Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, deployment, composer-php, bundle

I'm working with Symfony2 and need your help.

The project contains many bundles, each one handle some functionality. My need is to deploy the project after choosing which bundle I want to include.

For example, I have three bundles, the first manage the contacts, the second manage the stores and the third manage the products. I want to deploy the project with only the bundle that handle the products.

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Seems a bad idea. Instead you could disable / enable functionalities: checl out https://github.com/HotfloNL/FeatureToggleBundle

Comment: i already saw that bundle, but its not what i m looking for.

Comment: @COil Thanks for ure comments

i already saw that bundle, but its not what i m looking for.
For more details : 
in my company, wee deploy for our clients every month our new developpements, and wee dont have to deliver to a client a bundle he will not use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job that composer was developed for. You separate your bundles from your project and put them in their own repositories. What you can do then is add these repositories as sources via your composer file. The only thing you'd have to worry about when deploying a new application is which bundles you add to your composer dependencies.

If you run into issues like deployment or production server's inability to access your private repositories without a need for a private key or a password (which you obviously do not want to store in the composer file), you can deploy something called "Satis": https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Satis is a private Packagist-like tool that you host yourself so you can keep it on an internal network. When satis is up and running it's just as if you're installing dependencies from Packagist.